# объединения jquery скриптов

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Хочу реструктуризировать один большой jquery скрипт, разделив его на несколько поменьше. В частности, хочу вытащить все ajax-запросы в отдельный скрипт и обращаться к ним при необходимости. Сначала думал, что мне поможет import/export javascript, но внутри конструкции `$(document).ready(function()` импорт не работает

в экспортируемом скрипте пишу

```
export let one= 1 ;
```

В импортируемом скрипте пишу

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 import {one} from './test.js';
});
```

выдает ошибку `Unexpected token '{'`. Я правильно понял, что с jquery импорт/экспорт не дружит? Если да - подскажите пожалуйста что мне еще стоит почитать про "подключаться к сторонним скриптам и обмениваться между ними данными" если я использую jquery. Есть вариант использовать web-woker'ы, но похоже на костыль, задача то у них другая. Может что-то еще?

Comment: Jquery к слову тут не причем оказался

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если проблема только в `$(document).ready();`, то попробуй заменить её на аналог на нативном js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    //Your code
});
```

Или переделай структуру импортов так, чтобы не пришлось импортировать внутри callback функции

Comment: импорт/экспорт все таки не работают внутри функций, в том числе 'document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    //Your code
});'

Вы были правы, необходимо вызывать импорт вне функций, но можно отказаться от глобальной функции ожидания DOM дерева, так как указывая type="module" у скриптов, они начинают по умолчанию работать в отложенном режиме (defer), а значит будут ждать HTML документ прежде чем начать работать. 
Совет новичкам типа меня: после установки type "module" скрипт может "поломаться" так как также по умолчанию включается 'use strict'